# why can't /usr/local be mounted differently for different logged in user?

Tags: mount

at the moment `/usr/local` is owned by `root`, and user has to sudo out to install files locally, and programs installed will be available to other users (i.e. it's not local to the current user, but rather to the local machine/localhost), which doesn't make too much sense if you think about it.

so the question is , why can't we have `/usr/local` per user, and when system boots up, or when switch user, mount `/usr/local` from different physical path. So each user will run their `/usr/local` in a sandbox.

I believe this is the same idea as `%app_data` in windows. Is it possible for unix copy the same idea? or is there something I'm not aware of. thanks

Comment: It makes a great deal of sense in certain circumstances -- it's a tool available to all users. For per-user, you have /home/$USER. Lots of folks mount stuff in their /home. User-specific application data and customization (like, say, browser profiles) are indeed kept in each user's /home.

Comment: There is a per-user `local`: `$HOME/.local`. Why does the user need access to `/usr/local` if not make system-wide changes?

Comment: nice one @muru. you are right, we could have used ~/.local if i want to keep it to myself

Comment: `/usr` means Unix System Resources and has nothing to do with users ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is already a "local" folder per user.

It is in each user's home directory.

It is a hidden directory, because it is prefaced by a dot.

You can see it by executing

```
ls -la ~
```

You will see a directory listing similar to the following. Notice the `.local` directory.

```
drwxr-xr-x 29 someone someone  4096 Mar 29 10:14 .config
drwxr-xr-x  2 someone someone  4096 Feb 24 21:32 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 10 someone someone  4096 Mar 29 13:09 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  5 someone someone  4096 Mar 28 10:27 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x  3 someone someone  4096 Feb 24 21:32 .local
drwxr-xr-x  2 someone someone  4096 Feb 24 21:32 Music
drwxr-xr-x  2 someone someone  4096 Mar 26 22:57 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  4 someone someone  4096 Mar 23 15:39 Public
drwx------  2 someone someone  4096 Mar  2 18:48 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x  2 someone someone  4096 Feb 24 21:28 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 someone someone  4096 Feb 24 21:32 Videos
```

Comment: yeah forgot this one.thanks for reminding me that!